# Why my collectionview is slow when scrolling down or up? how to fix performance issue? I already Cleaned my UI Code

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why my collectionview is slow when scrolling down or up? how to fix performance issue?

I read all posts regarding this, and they mainly said to clean up your UI code. if UI code is complex than it will run slow. makes sense.

but here I already cleaned up my code. not much i can do here.

In collectionview  I have a label, and image. I am storeing label & path to image in a database. Image are store inside appdatadirectory

I think something is causing performance issues but i am not sure what?

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <!-- CollectionView -->
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <!-- Body -->
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <ContentView>
                              <grid>
                                <Frame CornerRadius="15" HasShadow="True" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding CardType}"
                                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                       BackgroundColor="Black"
                                                       TextColor="white"></Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <!-- Image -->
                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding CardFrontURL}"
                                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                            VerticalOptions="Fill"></Image>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                    
                     </grid>
                 </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- Header -->
                <CollectionView.Header>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="Cards List"  TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </CollectionView.Header>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

store label and image inside list

```
 public ObservableRangeCollection<MyModel> MyList{ get; set; }
```

Comment: is `CardFrontURL` a url or a file path?

Comment: CardFromURL is just a string. this string is a path to appdata folder on phone where image are stored

Comment: I see you've edited question to remove `ContentView` and `Grid`. Now, what about all those `StackLayout`s? [DO NOT edit them out of your question  - doing so would make this Q&A useless to anyone in the future - just report back whether following my instructions, to make a simpler layout that doesn't need as many of them, makes scrolling significantly faster, or not.] If the layout turns out not to be the cause, then say that - and we'll know my answer was not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to find out whether it is the `Image`s or your `DataTemplate` that is causing the slowdown.

Test: Remove the Image - comment out `<Image Source ...>`.

Does it run much faster? Then read about fetching and "caching" images, such that they can be quickly rendered.

---

If it isn't the images, then it is the structure of your `ItemTemplate`.

For each item, you create a `ContentView`, a `Grid`, and three `StackLayout`s. That's five `Layout` classes, per item.

Its almost never necessary to nest `StackLayout`s that are all vertical, as you did in your original code. Why do you think you needed those? Why don't you simply have ONE `StackLayout`, and put both `Label` and `Image` in it?

Likewise, why do you have the `Grid`?  What is it doing for you?

**A "clean UI" uses as few `Layout` classes as possible, per item.**

---

I believe you can reduce those five to ONE `Layout`:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Frame Padding="0,0,0,10" ...>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding CardType}" .../>
            <Image HeightRequest="200" Source="{Binding CardFrontURL}" .../>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
  </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

You'll likely need `Padding` or `Margin` on some items, to give vertical spacing that the `StackLayout`s were providing.

AFAIK, it is always possible to get desired spacing **without** adding another `Layout` class.

Worst case, you add a `BoxView` with a `HeightRequest`, and `BackgroundColor="Transparent"`.

---

NOTE:  `<Image HeightRequest="200" ...` - if a fixed height works for your needs, this allows layout logic to determine item height before reading image source, which helps make scrolling smooth. Without this, there may be one or more "hiccups" ("stutters", brief pauses) the first time you scroll the list, while the needed images are fetched.

---

OR use a `Grid`, for more flexibility in the future:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Frame Padding="0,0,0,10" ...>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding CardType}" .../>
            <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding CardFrontURL}" .../>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
  </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

`Grid` is great, because you can represent fairly elaborate layouts, by adding rows and columns, and still have only one layout class.

Comment: great tips, thank you!!! I learned a lot from this. I made all those changes. so now its scrolls up smoothly. But scrolling down, it get stuck only once now. this is way smoother than better than before!

Comment: @StarGates - sweet!  Glad this helped.

Comment: @StarGates - Improving the case where it "gets stuck once", probably requires *pre-caching* images. When your page first loads, you fire off a background thread that starts fetching the image URLs, and storing those images in a dictionary. Its a bit tricky to get right, because you've got a background thread adding to dictionary, while foreground (UI) is trying to read from dictionary. If it isn't in the dictionary yet, you have to prioritize fetching the needed one first. A future topic for you to explore. :)

Comment: yeah def research that

Comment: @StarGates - If you add `HeightRequest="NN"` to `Image`, where NN means some specific value you determine is useful, such as "50", then the layout logic can determine item height before it reads the image Source. This might help that one-time glitch.

Comment: wow you are good man, its worked!! I set `HeightRequest` to `200` and its all smooth now . thanks! put that in solution as well so other can see it too

Comment: also, remoed `VerticalOptions` to `Fill` inorder to make it smooth

Answer (score 0):

I get solution
Load items asynchronously, at the constructor add one element and in task after same times add other elements.

ex:

```
internal void SetData(CheckListData listData)
{
    _listData = listData;
    BindingContext = _listData;

   _items= new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxItem>(_listData.Items.Take(1));
    collectionView.ItemsSource = _items;
    loadData();
}

private void loadData()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        foreach (var item in _listData.Items.Skip(1))
            _items.Add(item);
    });
}
```